# .slice() doesn't work with foreach loop

Tags: php, jquery

I have a problem with button "load more" for elements in the foreach loop. Normally without foreach loop .slice() is working fine. Now .slice(0,4) is showing only first element. Is there any way to do this with the loop?
My code:

```
$info=$wpdb->get_results('SELECT user_login FROM wp_users WHERE company_district="London"');    
 foreach ($info as $info_res) {     
        $id             = $info_res->id;
        $login      = $info_res->user_login;
        echo '<div id="comment" style="display:none;"><p>'.$login.'</p></div>';

    }

    ?>
```

And Script:

```
<a href="#" id="loadMore">Load More</a>

<script>  
$(function () {
    $("#comment").slice(0, 4).show();
    $("#loadMore").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#comment:hidden").slice(0, 4).slideDown();
        if ($("#comment:hidden").length == 0) {
            $("#load").fadeOut('fast');
        }
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        }, 1500);
    });
});
</script>
```

I want to show first 4 elements, then after click show more or all.

Comment: `id` __must be unique__. Use classes. Over.

Comment: id should be unique for each element

Comment: [jQuery: ID Selector (“#id”)](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/): `[...]Each id value must be used only once within a document. If more than one element has been assigned the same ID, queries that use that ID will only select the first matched element in the DOM.[...]`

Comment: Thanks. Now its working! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved solution from question to answer:

> Problem solved. Thanks. ID must be unique. I used class instead of ID.